# How to show sold out tag image on out of stock product in magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to show the sold out tag image on out of stock product on category page

can any one help me ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Copy list.phtml from:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml
> to

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

In `list.phtml` you can check product is saleable or not like:

```
<?php if (!$_product->getIsSalable()): ?>
     <div class="out-of-stock"><img src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/outofstock.png'); ?>' alt="out of stock"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Note**: put `outofstock.png` at app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/web/images